# the method in the type is not applicable for the arguments java

Tags: java, object, methods

I have 2 methods in one class. from first i contains strings and return index. In 2nd I try to use this index to find element. But I have error in eclipse "the method containsStatsName() in the type SettingsPage is not applicable for the arguments java" What i have to do to work correctly??

SettingPage.class

```
public int containsStatsName(String statusName){
    int statListPos =0;
    int statsNumber = getStatusList.size();
     for(int i=0;i<statsNumber;i++){
         if(getStatusList.get(i).getText().toLowerCase().contains(statusName)){
             statListPos = i+1;
         }

         }
     return statListPos;     
}

public void editStatsName(){
    int leadNewPos = containsStatsName();
    int buttonNumber = getButtonList.size();
    int couterNew = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<buttonNumber;i++){
        if(couterNew == leadNewPos){
            getButtonList.get(i).click();           
            break;
        }else{
            couterNew++;
        }
    }   
}
```

MainPage.class

```
 SettingsPage sp = new SettingsPage(driver);

    sp.gotoLeadStat();

    sp.containsStatsName("new");

    sp.editStatsName();
```

Comment: int leadNewPos = containsStatsName(); requires String parameter.

Comment: but i want there use return statListPos;
so what i should do?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Take pen & paper and work through, it's easy to understand.

Comment: But i dont know how to solve it, im begginer, and I not the best in java. Can u tell mi what i should do to work it?

Comment: Nambari answered the question, the error is due to `containsStatsName()` since you didn't provide a String as a parameter. That function will return your `statListPos` if you provide any string for `statusName`... This is an **error that will not help future readers** (caused by "a simple typographical error"), therefore I'm flagging to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest the method **containsStatsName** as parameter of the 2nd method...

```
sp.gotoLeadStat();

sp.editStatsName(sp.containsStatsName("new"));
```

and modify the editStatsName Method.

```
public void editStatsName(int leadPosition){
int leadNewPos = leadPosition;
int buttonNumber = getButtonList.size();
int couterNew = 0;
for(int i=0;i<buttonNumber;i++){
    if(couterNew == leadNewPos){
        getButtonList.get(i).click();           
        break;
    }else{
        couterNew++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
public void editStatsName(){
        int leadNewPos = containsStatsName();
```

Your *containsStatsName* method takes a String parameter, there is no method with that name defined that takes no parameter, so the compiler tells you there is a problem.

You can modify your *editStatsName* method by giving it the parameter statusName:

```
public void editStatsName(String statusName){
        int leadNewPos = containsStatsName(statusName);
```

with that you give your *containsStatsName* method the parameter it needs.

But since the parameter that your *editStatsName* method **really** needs is the index and not the statusName - I would throw the *containsStatsName* method out of *editStatsName*, as you already call it in your main method:

```
public void editStatsName(int leadNewPos){
    int buttonNumber = getButtonList.size();
    int couterNew = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<buttonNumber;i++){
        if(couterNew == leadNewPos){
            getButtonList.get(i).click();           
            break;
        }else{
            couterNew++;
        }
    }
```

and call both methods in your main method like that:

```
int statListPos = sp.containsStatsName("new");

sp.editStatsName(statListPos);
```